# I am getting errors when I attempt to mutate my variable that has a color value stored in it

Tags: swift, swiftui

I currently have a list that takes in json data from a remotely stored file online. I have created a var 'hwcolor' which I store a color variable in it. I plan to mutate the value if a certain value from the json file is read.

`var hwcolor: Color = Color.white`

Here is my color variable.

```
List(fetcher.hws) { hw in
                        if hw.subject == "H2 Physics" {
                            self.hwcolor = Color.blue
                        }

                        else {
                            self.hwcolor = Color.white
                        }
```

The json file data loads up in the list properly and everything is in place. However, I am unable to get the color value to mutate according to the value read. I received an error 'Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable' from Xcode whenever I attempt to run the code. How should I change my code to allow the color variable to mutate?

```
         HStack {
                        VStack (alignment: .leading) {

                            Text(hw.title)
                                .foregroundColor(self.hwcolor)
                            Text(hw.info)
                                .font(.system(size: 14))
                                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                            Text(hw.duedate)
                                .font(.system(size: 11))
                                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        }
                            Spacer()
                            Text(hw.subject)
                                .padding()

                    }
                    }

                }
```

Here is the code that illustrates what I plan to have in each cell of a list.

Comment: You seem to be doing something _very_ wrong with SwiftUI. SwiftUI isn't supposed to be used like this. Please tell us more about why you are trying to mutate `hwcolor` _in a `List`_. You should also show more code to illustrate what you actually want to do.

Comment: @Sweeper I am attempting retrieve values from a json file and print them out into cells in a list. Each cell will have different text entries from the json file and I am planning to change the colours of the text according to the value retrieved from the json file.

Answer (score 1):

Just make it state, as below

```
@State var hwcolor: Color = Color.white
```

- SwiftUI view is struct and not modifiable, to have things changed of view itself, there is `@State` property wrapper, for model related things it is preferable to use `ObservableObject` pattern.